# How to install numpy and scipy for python 2.7.12, Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, python-2.7, numpy

I tried to install numpy using: `pip install numpy`

It worked, but I got a warning: 
`warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)`.

Then I tried to install scipy with: `python -m pip install --user scipy`   and it worked. I've checked my packages list with: `pip freeze` and both of them where on the list: `numpy==1.15.1   scipy==1.1.0`
But when I tried to import them in my code I got the following error.

```
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Original error was:

```
/home/spyros/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromObject
```

I tried to install the numpy again with the same way and the result was the same. Can you please help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: the best one I know of... 
O.K. Try this (based one experience in the past with Ubuntu + [this](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/download.html) and a little google.)

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip uninstall spicy
pip install spicy
pip install numpy
```

and if not, then this:

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev libatlas3-base libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev
```

and try the above again.

Comment: I uninstalled them successfully. I used pip install scipy but it didn't work, so I tried with 
pip install --user scipy and it worked. After pip install numpy it looks like numpy was already installed with scipy. Also, I got some RequestsDependencyWarning but when I try to import numpy and scipy in IDLE's terminal everything works fine. So that worked for me!

Comment: Good to know! Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

To install it for python 2.x, this works for me on ubuntu 18.04:
`sudo apt-get install python-scipy`

Comment: Excellent! this worked for me as well! (bookmarked as "tricks")